# Solr 4.0.0 define <uniqueKey> id</uniqueKey> as a "long" type throws an error on startup

Tags: java, solr, solrj

In my entity clas, I defined id:

```
@Field("id")
protected Long id;
```

then in solr4.0.0 schema.xml, i define:

```
<field name="id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

then solr throws exception on startup. If 'id' is defined as 'string' type, no exception. so my question is: what's the solution if i insisted on defining 'id' as long type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [SOLR-2997](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2997)
It seems QueryElevationComponent needs the Unique key in String format. So if you don't need it you can remove it.

Comment: You are quick and correct. I remove the <query> field in the conf/elevate.xml and its ok now!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the below node in solrconfig.xml file:

```
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >  
<!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->  
<str name="queryFieldType">string</str>  
<str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>  
</searchComponent>
```

Comment: i think that is what my answer was :)