# Id field as long type

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to use Id field as Long and getting this error:

```
ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'brands': Unable to create core 
[brands] Caused by: uniqueKey field (id) can not be configured to use a 
Points based FieldType: plong
```

Here is my schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema name="brands-config" version="1.6">
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true"/>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true"/>
<field name="name" type="string"/>
<field name="id" type="plong" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
</schema>
```

My solrconfig.xml is basic one - only removed the part mentioned [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208477/solr-4-0-0-define-uniquekey-id-uniquekey-as-a-long-type-throws-an-error-on) but it didn't help.

Is there any way to make my id field type long? I need it this way to avoid too much mapping.

Comment: You're going to have to use a string field instead, and then keep a separate field if you need to do int based range searches (the string field will work just fine for exact matches). Any reason why you can't do this?

Answer (score 3):

As described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10829) you can't use a point based field as uniqueKey.
Instead, you could use the `string` type.

Comment: Seems odd that one can't use an integer or long integer as the uniqueKey when virtually all the SQL databases support integer PKs.  Since many Solr applications will be using the engine to quickly index data from a SQL database, it would be most convenient to use the native long rather than converting it to/from string form.

Answer (score -1):

I'm really not sure why you need to have long datatype. To answer your question Solr query elevation component uses the String as a key and hence your unique key cannot be a long.

If you need to work around on this then you might consider creating a copy field and have that as a long and use if for your operations.